# method ref from lambda

Tags: java, lambda

In one of the method we used lambda expression (below) nesting streams.

```
return req.gUs().stream()
.map((**cfg) -> {
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get);
```

I want to move part of the code using some helper methods and method reference (below).

```
(cfg) -> {
return rsp.getUs().stream()
.filter(result.getId())    
.map((result) -> gEvent(index, Builder, cfg));
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the signature of `Stream.map()` and go from there.

Comment: Besides the nested lambdas (your cfg -> {} method should really be moved to its own method), the method looks fine to me.

Comment: What you need is [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)

Comment: There is no sense in using `.map(function_returning_stream).flatMap(stream -> stream)`; you can just use `.flatMap(function_returning_stream)` in the first place. Further, there is no need to write `(cfg) -> { return expression; }`, you can just write `cfg -> expression`. Now, also remove all obsolete brackets and you have halved the code…

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method, that returns a Function:

```
return req.getUs().stream()
.map(myFunction(rsp, index, headerBuilder))
.flatMap(stream -> stream)
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get);

private Function<CFGType, GenerateReturnType> myFunction(RspType rsp, IndexType index, HeaderType header){
  return (cfg) -> {
    return rsp.getPerUs().stream()
    .filter((result) -> cfg.getId() == result.getId())
    .filter((result) -> result.getCode() == ResultCode.SUCCESS)
    .map((result) -> generateEvent(index, headerBuilder, cfg));
  }
}
```

Or you could use a method reference if the rsp, index and header are fields:

```
return req.getUs().stream()
.map(this::myFunction)
.flatMap(stream -> stream)
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get);

private GenerateType myFunction(CFGType cfg) {
  return rsp.getUs().stream()
  .filter((result) -> cfg.getUsChId() == result.getChId())
  .filter((result) -> result.getResultCode() == ResultCode.SUCCESS)
  .map((result) -> generateEvent(index, headerBuilder, cfg));
}
```

Comment: Ok, I made a typo in the myFunction signature. Should be myFunction(CFGType cfg).

Comment: And I assumed, that rsp is a field in the class.

Comment: The CFGType, RspType and GenerateRemoveEventReturnType just the placeholders for the types which are written somewhere in the rest of your class.